# Mysql database dropdown menu when selected needs to pull data from the new column of the database and put in a text field

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

I have a 3 column database

1--id
2--project
3--costCentre

I have made the (2) column project as a dropdown option and I would like to populate a text field with the data from the (3) column as dropdown is selected.

The code below is mirroring the dropdown box result in the text field is it an easy tweak.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#project').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('project'));
$(function(){
    $('#selectdata').change(function(){
        $('#softwares').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('project'));
    });
});
});
</script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    
    <!-- Panel -->
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Get data from drop down list into textbox</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    
    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Softwares List :</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectdata">
    <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db   = "database";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    echo "<option>-Select One-</option>";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM projects") or die (mysqli_error());
    while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['project']."' data-project='".$row['project']."'>".$row['project']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Textbox -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Softwares :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="softwares">
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)